# Cancelling Item_Open causes crash

Tags: c#, vsto, outlook-addin, outlook-2016

I am writing an office addin using c# and Microsoft.Interop libraries. 
When I cancel the opening of an appointment in the Item_Open event by setting the Cancel property to false, it causes Outlook to crash with an Appcrash. The crash happens when opening an appointment of a recurring series with attendees.

This is somewhat new in 2016. In 2010 and 2013 it used to work.

Has anyone any idea how to get this working in 2016?

I tried to identify the problem in my code but even the example found [here](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/ff973716(v=office.14).aspx) (Which also works for 2016 in other regards) breaks if i just set cancel to true in the AppointmentItem open event.

**Edit:** I just found out this only happens if I disable the cache mode

**Edit 2:** I just found out this only happens in 2016 in 2019 and o365 (that were automatically updated to 2019) it seems to work again.

Comment: As Eugene Astafiev mentioned I of course set the bool to false ... sorry for the confusion

Comment: December and Still broken ...

Answer (score 1):

> When I cancel the opening of an appointment via setting the Cancel bool to false in the Item_Open event causes outlook to crash

To cancel the default action you need to set the [Cancel](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/ff865989.aspx) parameter to true. Setting the Cancel parameter to false shouldn't prevent item from opening in the inspector window.

Make sure that no other add-ins are enabled in Outlook.

Comment: This was exactly what I did. To ensure its nothing related to my other code, I used the "vanilla" example from the Link above.

Comment: I think we are also discussing this Topic over at the MSDN forums where I posted it in hope somebody from MS would see it

Comment: For anyone Interested [MSDN Link](https://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/en-US/720cb271-492f-4a13-9251-73b46dbdcd66/cancelling-itemopen-causes-outlook-appcrash-possible-bug?forum=outlookdev#9d4d21ee-2a85-45c2-92b8-92dd1b37e9ab) If a Solution should be found there I'll post it here of course